# Typing path length using shortest path dijkstra()

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

I am now trying to get the length of a shortest path using `dijkstra()`. I need it to find all the points in my sample, which are located more than 25 km away along roads from district centres. I will loop it, but before I do this I need to get the path's length.

When I enter the following code, it only shows me the shortest path highlighted in red, but not its length. How can I modify it in order to get length in km? (In case it is important, my crs is North_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *

vl = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)

pStart = QgsPoint(2327292.145, -2732901.348)
pStop = QgsPoint(2328327.741, -2732822.68)

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
graph = builder.graph()

tStart = tiedPoints[0]
tStop = tiedPoints[1]

idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
idStop = graph.findVertex(tStop)
(tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, idStart, 0)
if tree[idStop] == -1:
  print ("Path not found")
else:
  p = []
  curPos = idStop
  while curPos != idStart:
    p.append(graph.vertex(graph.arc(tree[curPos]).inVertex()).point())
    curPos = graph.arc(tree[curPos]).outVertex();
    p.append(tStart)
  rb = QgsRubberBand(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
  rb.setColor(Qt.red)
  for pnt in p:
    rb.addPoint(pnt)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) that introduces you to this site and its protocols. In your question you talked about a path highlighted in red, but there's no reference to it: maybe you may add a screenshot of what do you see for better explaining your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your question is how long is the path represented as points in `p`. Since you are using a projection that is in meters it is simply a case of iterating through `p` and calculating the distance to the last/next point.

So something like:

```
lastPoint = None
d = 0
for point in p:
    if lastPoint is not None:
         dx = point.x - lastPoint.x
         dy = point.y - lastPoint.y  
         d += sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
     lastPoint = point
print "distance is "+str(d/1000.0)+"km"
```